# Should the View pass data inserted from user to Controller or should the Controller get data from View's fields? (MVC Pattern)

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, sequence-diagram

My View has a textfield and a button. According to MVC pattern on button click should be called a function of the controller. This function should do some operation on the View's textfield content. It is a job of the View to pass the String contained in the textfield or should the controller grab it?

To let you understand here are the two sequence diagram:

[image]

Which one best fits MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Both diagrams only show the `V` and `C` of `MVC`. The missing `M` is, ironically, the answer to your question:

---

> Data is exchanged between a `View` and a `Controller` using a `Model`

---

The `DATA` itself is at the center of everything. The **responsibility** of each element and the **relationship** between the elements of MVC is determined by each elements  relationship with the data:

- `Model` - *contains* the data
- `View` - *displays* the data
- `Controller` - *manages* the data

Answer (score 0):

Transient data should be passed with the event itself. This would essentially be the delta to be applied to a hypothetical model.

Extraneous data would need to be queried as needed by the controller.

Also this isn't MVC. MVC is a small talk pattern. The controller is a single literal function specialised to handle a single event type and is passed the view-model, data-model, and transient event data.

I think this is closer to an MVP (Model View Presenter). Here the Presenter is capable of managing a number of event types in order to present an aggregate behaviour. The same advice applies though. Events are passed event related transient data. Although now it makes little sense to pass the view and model along too, the presenter is already well aware of that information.

Comment: So which sequence diagram makes more sense to you?

Comment: Again context matters here. A Mouse Movement event would crucially need to know which mouse, and the mouse co-ordinates of from and to locations (seen as they change frequently). It certainly isn't important to pass along the colour of the control to understand the event, therefor this would be better looked up from the controller. On the otherhand a colour change event would be sent with the colours (from and to), but lack details such as mouse and mouse co-ordinates, if required the controller would need to request these.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody outside your view should ever know about text fields, buttons and so on. Instead outside code would know about some text, and the view would know how to display it. Instead of telling the outside of a button, the view should tell the outside that the user wants some action to happen.